# Refreshing ArcIMS service with ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, arcims

Does anyone know if it is possible to refresh an ArcIMS service with ArcObjects and if so do you have a nice code snippet? :)

I think it might have something to do with interface IIMSAxlRequest - but not sure how to use it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't use ArcObjects.

Your best bet is too just restart the ArcIMS services.
Simply doing a refresh like you would in the admin console may not 
refresh any fields that have been added or removed from the map service.
Only a restart of the services will guarantee that.

You could script the restart with a batch file.

```
net stop "ArcIMS Tasker 10.0.0"
net stop "ArcIMS Monitor 10.0.0"
net stop "ArcIMS Application Server 10.0.0"
net start "ArcIMS Application Server 10.0.0"
net start "ArcIMS Monitor 10.0.0"
net start "ArcIMS Tasker 10.0.0"
```

You could also remove the map service and add it back in if you don't want to take down ArcIMS Services.

Comment: How annoying is that! - It would have been so nice to have some simple method you could call instead of resorting to clunky command line commands from code. Grrr.  But thanks for confirming things there.

Comment: Yes its one of the major annoyances of ArcIMS. I actually have an instance of ArcIMS with over a hundred services that get torn down and rebuilt every night. Just make sure the newest fields are in there.